# When other people answer more comprehensively than me, should I delete my answer?

Tags: discussion

In [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50013307/how-to-append-temporary-value-to-db-value), I answered faster, but the question then got a better answer which makes me look stupid and like a plagiarist. Should I delete my own answer and then improve the other answer (for instance, by adding a documentation link that is in my answer), or just keep my answer and improve it?

Comment: (1) As the accepted answer to the target question points out, it "comes down to a judgement call" -- it is a question of how much better the other answer is and how much significant extra content your answer has. (2) In the specific case you mention here, I feel deleting your answer and making the edit was indeed the right call. (By the way, in order to make the edit as unobtrusive as possible, I took the liberty to adjust your edit to (a) blend the link into the rest of the text and (b) leave just the official documentation link.)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, I'm happy to accept @duplode

Comment: *"which makes me look stupid and like a plagiarist"* - no it doesn't. It just makes you seem like someone answering with too much haste. Accusing someone of plagiarism when the timeline clearly proves otherwise - now that would be stupid.